# Performance issue Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey I am having a performance issue and and I am really lost why it occurs.

The problem lies in the `WHERE` clause. I want to select the most recent available date that is available in the dataset. If I create a `VARCHAR(8)` (or `Date` datatype, doesn't really matter) and set it to a value like `20210303` and then filter on that parameter, the query takes about **30 seconds**. However, when I use a `MAX` function on the dataset and obtain the same value (`20210303`) and filter on that via a subquery it takes about **TEN times longer**.

Of course, an obvious remark would be that perhaps applying the `MAX` function takes really long, but that isn't the case, because when I run the subquery on its own I don't get this problem. And the craziest thing is when I replace the parameter with a literal value (in this case it would be `20210303`) it also drastically degrades in performance?!

I am really lost on this issue. The column that I apply the filter on is **indexed** btw, so that can't be the issue either.

Would really appreciate some help and I would happily give more info if someone needs it.

EDIT: can't add the actual query, I can give however an outline of it:

```
SELECT
    A.val1,
    A.val2,
    B.val1,    
    C.val1,
    etc,
    SUM(A.Value)
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON  A.FK_B = B.FK_A
        AND A.Date = B.Date
        AND A.Location = B.Location

    LEFT JOIN C
        ON  C.FK_C = B.FK_C
        AND C.Date = A.Date
        AND C.Location = A.Location

    INNER JOIN D
        ON  A.FK_D = D.FK_A
        AND A.Date = D.Date
        AND A.Location = D.Location
    --other joins that are very similar to the ones above

WHERE 1=1
    AND A.Date = @Date
    AND A.Location IN (Loc1, Loc2, ...)
    AND A.Filter1 = Filter1
    AND etc.
GROUP BY
    A.val1,
    A.val2,
    B.val1,    
    C.val1,
    etc,
HAVING
    SUM(A.VALUE)  <>  0
```

All tables have the column `Date` **indexed**. If more info is needed, then please say so.

Comment: A performance issues without a query is rather like . . . well, forget the analogy.  Without code, the question is incomplete.

Comment: yes , please provide your query ( the whole) not only part that you have issue , also maybe provide the execution plan  , use [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Also can you tell us if you have an index on that field, and provide some basic table structure for the table.

Comment: "*If I create a VARCHAR(8) (or Date datatype, doesn't really matter)*" - on the contrary. It matters **a lot**. Never store date (or date/time) values in `varchar` columns. This site is full of people seeking help because of this kind of wrong doing

Comment: Please tag which version of sql server and provide 1. The query, 2, the schema of all tables involved, 3, indexes and any constraints on the tables, the problematic execution plan via [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: I have added the outline of the query. I can't access the execution the plan as I don't have access to it. Also, regarding the comment that datatype does matter, I understand that, but I meant in the context of my query that both varchar and date datatypes had the exact same performance.

Comment: Let's see, if I understand what you are telling us: You say that the query with `AND A.Date = @Date` is fast, but with `AND A.Date = (select max(some_date) from somewhere)` instead it becomes slow?

Comment: Yes, A.Date = @Date runs in half a minute, but A.Date = (SELECT MAX(A.date) FROM A Where A.date < @Date) takes way longer.

Comment: Yep, that's weird. A glitch in the optimizer I'd say.

Comment: If it is indeed a glitch, is there anything I can do about It?

Comment: Well, isn't using a variable already a viable workaround? I prefer aggregation before joining by the way. This usually leads to working with smaller intermediate results and can thus sometimes result in a faster running query.

Comment: It is not really a work around as whenever I use the subquery in the WHERE clause, which I need  to do as I need the max available date below a reporting date, I get the terrible runtime...

Comment: When working with variables, you don't need a subquery. 1. You have a variable @Date. 2. You use it to get the max date: `SELECT @Maxdate = MAX(A.date) FROM A Where A.date < @Date;`. 3. You use that variable in your query: `AND A.Date = @Maxdate`.